# Xcode only generate generic xcode archive

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, archive

My archive can only generate generic xcode archive. I tried nearly all solutions online, but still no luck.
[image]

What I have done so far

1. In schema, build only has one app target for archive 
   [image]
2. Every library, set skip install to YES, and remove installation path 
   [image]
   [image]
3. app target set skip install to NO 
   [image]
4. Headers in build phase for every library only contain headers in project section.
   [image]

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.8
xcode: 10.2.1

BTW, I have some target dependencies as below, but I don't see any relation.

[image]

And I am archiving using production provision file. If I build with it, 
it complains about entitlement signing issue, but it doesn't look like related either.

[image]

That's pretty every solution I could find online, what did I miss, I have been struggling with this for days. Is there a way to debug what is missing, eg console logs??? Any help appreciated.

Comment: What sort of archive do you want to build?  A generic archive is fine for distribution via the App Store

Comment: Everything depends on _what_ you archived to start with. If you wanted to end up with something that could be turned into an app, you needed to archive _the app target_. Looks like you didn't do that.

Comment: @Paulw11 I want to distribute through App Store as long as use in testFlight. How do I distribute a generic archive? I read online tutorial, there should be a button to upload, but there is no button if I generate generic xcode archive.

Comment: What happens when you click "Distribute content"?

Comment: @matt Yes, I want to have an app to distribute through app store and use in testFlight. Could you elaborate "archive the app target", I am a xcode newbie. in the graph you can see, my target is umr_app_ios, that is the shown on the top left corner of xcode run button. I assume that's how we set the archive target?

Comment: @Paulw11  it shows two options, built product and archives. Both of them export a directory locally on my laptop.

Comment: As Matt says, it doesn't look like you have generated an app archive.  I'm afraid I don't know the process for using React - With a native app you simply select the app target and click "archive".  Have you added your Apple ID login details to Xcode preferences?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958855/finished-react-native-project-on-pc-now-i-want-to-use-xcode-on-my-mac-to-create/

Comment: Thanks for helping, unfortunally, that's not a solution for me.